# Keep the UITableViewCell marked when switching from searchResultsTableView and tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a a table view that displays search results. I want to mark some cell checked when I select row at some `indexPaths`. and later when I try to search something and the search results contains the previous marked cell, how to show this cell which is marked in the search results tableview? Right now I am using a `NSMutableArray` to add and remove selected `indexPaths` when I select rows. But if I search in search bar, and previous marked cell won't been marked in search results tableview. What's the better to way to keep track of selected rows?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a `BOOL selected` to the model object you are using as the data source of the table view. You can set this value when you make a selection on the table view. While searching indexPath of the selected rows being changed but, if you mark the selection in the data source, it is not going to change.

Comment: What if I don't use core data. Just a array as the data source?

Comment: I didnt mean core data. Array is enough. Objects within the array could be an object contain the property isSelected